# Captcha with premade images

Tags: php, captcha

I've built my own custom captcha system from a series of 20 images I previously made in Photoshop, then linking them in a DB table called "captcha" to their codes. I'm not sure if this method is safe, as long as the images are difficult for a spam bot to read, which I think they are, instead of generating the captcha images on the fly, which would consume more processing time, but maybe this is the only recommended way to do it.

What do you think about this?

Comment: The moment someone notices that you use a vast amount of pictures, they can obtain all possible answers and try one.
This means you have a 1/20 chance that the bot will be recognized as a human.
So it's obvious that you have a higher possibility that bots will still pass your safety system.

But as long as nobody notices that you are using only 20 images... then it doesn't really matter (compared to normal captcha services).

Comment: It's not possible that a bot figures out what code goes for a given image unless it "reads" the captcha (because it is a bad captcha). I don't think there is a 1/20 chance of a bot to pass the captcha system. An on-the-fly system will always be more secure, but I don't consider mine as insecure as you say.

Comment: It depends if your site is targeted dependently or not. If it is, then someone might notice that you're only using a few captchas. For example, if I'm visiting your site a few times, I probably encountered a few captchas too. The moment I notice a re-occuring captcha, I know there is a flaw in your security system. Then it's only a matter of time to write a bot that uses that one and only captcha. If I create 20 accounts and use the captcha "bsdqshd", 1/20 will pass through.

Comment: That's right. But only in case a hacker finds out first, and then creates a specific bot for it. This wouldn't be the case with a random bot reaching my web through a search engine or something.

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment too. Quoting the first sentence: "The moment someone notices that you use a vast amount of pictures".
Indeed, if it's just a random bot it doesn't matter, that's what I said in my last sentence in my first post.

Comment: ok, you're completely right. Now, imagine my situation. I've re-built my personal website (it's not public yet so I can't show you), and I wanted the contact form to be present everytime, in the footer. There is a link in the main menu above which triggers a scrollTo (jQuery plugin) to the contact form. So, everytime the page loads, the captcha must be generated. Wouldn't a solution like user1579327 said in the answer below good enough? It's very unlikely that a person finds out that a captcha with around 10000 images is not being generated on the fly.

Comment: (...see previous comment). Maybe it's not the best solution for an enterprise web, but considering it's a personal website, I think a spammer should be too bored and idle to be testing random pages manually to find out where to send their spam. I thought on an intermediate situation, which would be to have the contact form collapsed, and when someone wants to send something, the forms is opened and the captcha is generated on the fly through ajax. But for this moment I don't consider it necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the same.

But just because the site is not **strong targeted** by spammers.

I was able to cut away all the bot-generated spam.

Only thing, 20 images are far too few.

I setup an applescript that generated 10000 images from 0000 to 9999.

The script was creating the document, drawing the numbers, rotating and translating a little randomly, then applying some filters I set up on an Action inside PS.

Also every image was given a pseudo random filename (ex. `876376.jpg` for the `1234` number image) and a table map was generated to have a relation between every number and the corresponding filename.

---

**Why one would chose this approach and reinvent the wheel instead of using reCAPTCHA?**

Two reason:

1. reCAPTCHA is bulletproof but sometimes is annoying for the user.
2. reCAPTCHA stores Google's cookies on the user's device. In order to comply with UE's regulations and GDPR you may need to setup or extend informative banners about cookies and Privacy Policies' pages.

Comment: Respect! And you have been entering codes (according to images).. manually? Or how?

Comment: I guess the script also handled populating the database automatically with the real codes and the randomly generated file names. Is there any php script available out there to do this?

Comment: when the script was generating image for number 1234 was also generating its "random code", let say 8374647.  The random code was used to give a name to the jpeg (8374647.jpg), then it was put on a string along with the number represented. This way: "1234" & tabulator & "8374647" & linefeed. Every number was added to the string that was then saved to disk as a plain text file and imported into the DB as a tab-separated-values text file.

Comment: I'm going to follow your advice and will implement my own script to generate around 10000 images and automatically populate the database.